# distutils ignores changes to setup.py when building an extension?

Tags: python, c, pip, distutils, setup.py

I have a setup.py file that builds an extension.  If I change one of the source files, distutils recognizes this and rebuilds the extension, showing all the compile / link commands.

However, if the only thing I change is setup.py (I'm fiddling trying to make library dependencies work), then it doesn't seem to rebuild (e.g., none of the compile/link commands show up).  I've tested this by removing one of the source files in the line

```
sources = ['foo.c', 'bar.c' ...]
```

and when I `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py install`, it still creates a new file for the extension, but it must be a version cached somewhere, since it shouldn't compile.

How do I clear this cache?  I have tried

```
python setup.py clean --all
```

or using the `--ignore-installed` and `--no-cache-dir` flags when doing `pip install -e .`

The only way I have found to make it rebuild is if I add garbage in a source file, triggering a rebuild and error, remove the garbage, and `pip install -e .` again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Just delete under `site-packages` path any file related to it, you may find sometimes more than one version or some files packaged as zip files or run the following command `python setup.py clean --all`.
2. Recompile and install again.

But I will recommend to use `python setup.py develop` so you don't need to reinstall it with every change, you will be able to frequently edit your code and not have to re-install it again.  `python setup.py install` is used to install typically a ready to use third-party packages.

Check here to better understand [python packaging](http://www.ewencp.org/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-packaging-python/).

**Summary**:

```
python setup.py clean --all
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: Thanks!  `python setup.py develop` was exactly what I needed.  But deleting under site-packages didn't work for me.  I had to `python setup.py clean --all` and then `python setup.py develop`.  That worked without deleting anything under `site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run

```
python setup.py clean --all
python setup.py develop
```

Thanks to DhiaTN for getting me there.