# Recompile Cython extension when setup.py changed with Pip editable

Tags: compilation, cython

How do I make `pip` recompile Cython extensions when I have only changed `setup.py` when installing in `editable` mode. Currently it always skips the extensions. There are many questions related to this for `distutils` but I can't see any answers for `pip`.

To be clear, I have a `setup.py` like the following

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy

ext_modules = []

# simulate_fast
ext_modules += [
    Extension("adio.simulating.simulate_fast_c",
        sources=["./adio/simulating/simulate_fast/simulate_fast_c.pyx",
                 "./adio/simulating/simulate_fast/c/simulate_fast.c",
                 "./adio/simulating/simulate_fast/c/matrix.c"],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
        extra_compile_args=["-Ofast", "-ffast-math", "-march=native"],
        language='c',
        libraries=["gsl", "openblas"],
        define_macros=[('FLOAT32', 1)]
        )
    ]

setup(
  name="adio",
  packages=["adio"],
  cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

Now if I delete the `('FLOAT32', 1)` in `define_macros` of course I would like the Cython extension to recompile.

However when I run

```
python3 -m pip install --editable -U . -v
```

I receive the following output as part of the output

```
running develop
running egg_info
writing adio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to adio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to adio.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'adio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'adio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
skipping './adio/simulating/simulate_fast/simulate_fast_c.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
```

I have tried the `-I` and `--force-reinstall` flag with `pip` but it always skips the Cython extension. If I am not using editable mode then I can run

```
python3 -m pip install -U . -v
```

and this does recompile. How can I achieve the same thing when using the `--editable` flag.

**Related**

[distutils ignores changes to setup.py when building an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928001/distutils-ignores-changes-to-setup-py-when-building-an-extension)

Comment: I don't think you can. I usually delete the `.c` file generated from the `.pyx` file to force recompilation in these cases.

Comment: So you will use something like this `find . -name *.pyx | sed -e "s/.pyx/.c/g" | xargs rm`? I wonder if this could ever be 'dangerous'.